# Node.js and Mongoose - map populated array inside object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have 2 schemas - "Category" and "Tag".
Each Category has an array of tags linked to it.
What I'm trying to achieve is: get category by id with its tags populated but instead of returning the category with array of tag objects I would like to map the tags to an array of tags names:

This approach below is not working, The returned Category has still an array of tag objects instead of tag names

```html
const getById = async (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    let category;
    let tags;
    try {
        category = await Category.findById(id)
            .populate('tags');
        if (!category) throw new HttpError("Could not find category with the provided id", 400);
        tags = category.tags.map(tag => tag.name);
        category.tags = tags;
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }

    const statusCode = 200;
    res.status(statusCode).json({
        category,
        code: statusCode,
        message: "Success"
    });
}
```

```html
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const categorySchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Enter name'],
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    set: name => capitalizeFirstLetter(name)
},
dateCreated: {type: Date, default: new Date(), get: (dateCreated) => moment(dateCreated)},
tags: [{type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag'}],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

```html
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const tagSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Enter name'],
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    set: name => capitalizeFirstLetter(name)
},
dateCreated: {type: Date, default: new Date(), get: (dateCreated) => moment(dateCreated)}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Tag", tagSchema);
```

Comment: Try `category = await Category.findById(id).populate('tags').lean()`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```html
const getById = async (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    let category;
    let tags;
    try {
        category = await Category.findById(id)
            .populate('tags').lean();
        if (!category) throw new HttpError("Could not find category with the provided id", 400);
        tags = category.tags.map(tag => tag.name);
        category.tags = tags;
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }

    const statusCode = 200;
    res.status(statusCode).json({
        category,
        code: statusCode,
        message: "Success"
    });
}
```